# SSRS Expression To Remove Leading 0 In Date

Tags: datetime, ssrs-2008, ssrs-expression

My report displays the date time as "Friday, May 08, 2015" but I'd like to remove the 0 in the date field if the value is a single digit.

[image]

Should I use an expression to handle this? And if so, could I get some help on the expression?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use an expression, the expression will look like this (replace `Now()` with your date value)

`=Format(Now(), "dddd, MMM d, yyyy")`

Comment: Thanks very much - simple and straight forward.

Answer (score 2):

It is best practice to use this expression:

```
=Format(Now(), "dddd, MMM d, yyyy")
```

with

- `dddd` the week day
- `MMM` the month
- `d` the day of the month
- `yyyy` the year on 4 digits